# Can I recover a different version of a file on VSCode after clicking the wrong button on "resolve save conflict"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I opened VSCode and was presented with a notification that there was a conflict between two versions of a file. I followed the prompts and got a side-by-side comparison of two versions. I clicked the button that accepts the newer version, believing that VSCode had correctly inferred which version was newer. It had not, and I lost a significant number of changes to the file. Is there a cached copy of the other version anywhere?

Thank you!

ps - I seem to have failed to actually commit the changes in git as well. Not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 0):

After searching through the VSCode appdata, I concluded that it wasn't likely that there was a copy. I found a copy of the bytecode (`.pyc` file) and used [uncompyle6](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/) to get an approximate copy of the version of the `.py` file I needed to recover.  Was able to manually merge from there.

Answer (score 0):

I was flummoxed by this one too. The answer is that you can restore the old version by hitting undo until before the change was made.